# ManyToOne causes not mapped to a single property

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am getting the following exception:

> Failed to create sessionFactory
>   object.org.hibernate.AnnotationException:
>   referencedColumnNames(wojid_fk, powid_fk, id, rodzgm_fk) of
>   com.darek.Persistance.teryt.Miejscowosc.gmina referencing
>   com.darek.Persistance.teryt.Gmina not mapped to a single property

That's my Miejscowosc class:

```
//imports
(...)

@Entity
@Table(name = "miejscowosc")
public class Miejscowosc {

    public Miejscowosc(int id, String nazwa, boolean nazwazwyczajowa,
            RodzajMiejscowosci rodzmiejsc, Gmina gmina, int idpod, Date stanna) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.nazwa = nazwa;
        this.nazwazwyczajowa = nazwazwyczajowa;
        this.stanna = stanna;
        this.rodzmiejsc = rodzmiejsc;
        this.gmina = gmina;
        this.idpod = idpod;
        }

protected Miejscowosc() {
    super();
}

@Id
@Column(columnDefinition = "MEDIUMINT(7)")
private int id;

@Column(columnDefinition = "MEDIUMINT(7)")
private int idpod;

@Column(columnDefinition = "CHAR(36)")
private String nazwa;

@Column(name = "nazwazwyczajowa", columnDefinition = "BIT", length = 1)
private boolean nazwazwyczajowa;

@Column(columnDefinition = "DATE")
private Date stanna;

@JoinColumn(name = "rodzmiejsc_fk", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne
private RodzajMiejscowosci rodzmiejsc;

@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "wojid_fk", referencedColumnName = "wojid_fk"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "powid_fk", referencedColumnName = "powid_fk"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "gmid_fk", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "rodzgm_fk", referencedColumnName = "rodzgm_fk") })
@ManyToOne
private Gmina gmina;


//getters and setters
(...)

}
```

And that's my Gmina class:

```
//imports
(...)
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Entity
@Table(name = "gmina")
public class Gmina {

public Gmina(int id, String nazwa, String nazwadod, Date stanna) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.nazwadod = nazwadod;
    this.nazwa = nazwa;
    this.stanna = stanna;
}

protected Gmina() {
    super();
}

@Id
@Column(columnDefinition = "SMALLINT")
private int id;

@Column(columnDefinition = "CHAR(50)")
private String nazwadod;

@Column(columnDefinition = "CHAR(36)")
private String nazwa;

@Column(columnDefinition = "DATE")
private Date stanna;

@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "powid_fk", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "wojid_fk", referencedColumnName = "wojid_fk", insertable = false, updatable = false) })
@ManyToOne
private Powiat powiat;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "rodzgm_fk", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private RodzajGminy rodzGm;

//getters and setters
(...)

}
```

How can I resolve this problem and why does the problem exist?
Thank you in advance for help.

EDIT:

Both gmina table and miejscowosc table have column **wojid_fk**, **powid_fk** and **rodzgm_fk** and that's the reason why I have the same names of them. And the only difference is that gmina has **id** while miejscowosc has **gmid_fk** (foreign key to **id**)

Answer (score -1):

You need yo use `@JoinColumns` like as follows

```
@JoinColumns({    
  @JoinColumn(name = "first", referencedColumnName = "column_name"),
  @JoinColumn(name = "second", referencedColumnName = "column_name"),
  @JoinColumn(name = "third", referencedColumnName = "column_name")
})
```

Comment: Isn't it the same as `@JoinColumns({
   @JoinColumn(name = "wojid_fk", referencedColumnName = "wojid_fk"),
   @JoinColumn(name = "powid_fk", referencedColumnName = "powid_fk"),
   @JoinColumn(name = "gmid_fk", referencedColumnName = "id"),
   @JoinColumn(name = "rodzgm_fk", referencedColumnName = "rodzgm_fk") })` ?

Both gmina table and miejscowosc table have column **wojid_fk**, **powid_fk** and **rodzgm_fk** and that's the reason why I have the same names of them. And the only difference is that gmina has **id** while miejscowosc has **gmid_fk** (foreign key to **id**)